# How to perform parallel processing of files (pdf,docs,txt, xls) in a directory on local folder on Desktop using PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, extract

I have about 9000 files in different sub directories in a single directory on my local desktop. Total size of the directory is about 15GB. I do not want to go through python programming approach, which is extremely time consuming. I would like to use some kind of distributed parallel processing for the task. I want to perform the follow

- Ingest all these files in a parallel manner.
- Extract text from these documents (I already have a tika based python script to extract the text from these files)
- Store the filename and the content (text extracted) in a dataframe.

I have already done the above task using normal python script. But I want to use Spark/pySpark to perform the above tasks. I have never used Spark before so need some guidance on what could be the roadmap.

How do i parallely pass these documents to Spark and then apply my extraction script to these documents? What approach can I take?

Comment: Iterate through your dir, take and parse each file with the Tika parser then bind the results to a dataframe. Otherwise you must write a custom reader based on Apache Tike for every file format. Also do your calculations every N iterations since the DAG will be very heavy if you execute it at once for all the documents

Comment: Yes, I am currently doing that using Apache Tika.

Answer (score 0):

spark is not optimal for pdf, xls, docx formats. These formats have their own type of compression and do not parallelize well. They need to be entirely loaded in memory to be decompressed.

The preferred compression formats are column oriented compression formats such as parquet, orc or flat files such as json, txt... These can be processed efficiently by parts without having to load the entire file in memory for decompression.

If you happen to have only text files, that have different structures or that are unstructured, then I recommend using spark's RDD API to read them:

```py
sc.wholeTextFiles(input_directory)
```

This will load the content of every text file and append the name of the file to each record.

Otherwise, parallelizing in python using `multiprocessing` will be more efficient.

Comment: Oh, No I have pdfs, docx, excel and image formats. Yes currently I am using multiprocessing in python. But that would also take a lot of time considering the number of files.

Comment: You will always be limited by the number of vcores that you have on your server. The only ways you could process these files faster is by: optimizing your code, scaling up (getting a bigger server) or scaling out (splitting your job to many servers so they can each process a batch and then concatenate the results)

Comment: How about I save the directory structure in a csv format with one of the columns have the path to every file in the directly. And then give this csv to spark engine to parallelize and map a function to extract text according to different extension type for each file(each row) which it is processing.

Comment: Applying computations within a `UDF` will only be as fast as your python process can go. The fact that your run it in tasks orchestrated by a resource manager not meant for this type of work won't make it faster. You'll even lose precious resources to the manager for it to distribute the tasks. Moreover, the number of tasks that can run in parallel is the number of vcores that you have on your server

Comment: CPU intensive processes like yours are better handled by linux shells than by distributed languages. They are better at handling RAM intensive processes